# Meaning of "by" when used with dates - inclusive or exclusive

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

If, in a contract fr example, the text reads: "X has to finish the work by MM-DD-YYYY", does the "by" include the date or exclude it?

In other words, will the work delivered on the specified date violate the contract?

Comment: You'll need to ask a lawyer.

Comment: I'd imagine the common understanding of this word is what the lawyers use, so I'm just interested in what native speakers thing.

Comment: To native speakers, there is **no definitive interpretation**. It could mean either "up to and *including*", or "*strictly before*". Which meaning it had in a specific context would depend upon the conventions governing that context, which can and do differ. If I wanted to be completely unambiguous, I would say something like "must be delivered *before* ...".  On the other hand, sometimes the ambiguity is irrelevant, no matter which convention governed it, if a bottle of milk said "Best *f used by* August 10th", you couldn't get me to drink it on that date. **TL;DR**: it's ambiguous.

Comment: Dan has said it all.  "To native speakers, there is no definitive interpretation."  It's that simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have specified, the word **by** is generally synonymous with **no later than** when referring to a date or time.

However, it is important to note (and this is why I am adding another answer) that if all you know is "The work must be completed by MM-DD-YYYY", then **the exact due date is still ambiguous**.

Without additional information, 'due by MM-DD-YYYY' has a fair chance of meaning:

- Due at or before 11:59:59 PM on that date - that is, before the specified day *ends*.
- Due at or before 11:59:59 PM on the previous date - that is, before the specified day *begins*.
- Due at or before a specific time on the date, such as *the end of the workday for the person receiving the work*.

(the below veers off the topic of the word's usage, but I thought it was worth adding)

Because of this ambiguity, it is extremely prudent to seek more clarification

- At what time on that date does the deadline occur?
- Is it problematic to be *too early*?

Comment: Thank you! I liked Tim's answer because of the cited references, but you added some more to that, especially regarding my context.